# Multiply matrices with big size

Tags: matlab, matrix, large-data

I wanna to try calculate multiply of three matrix in matlab.
The formation of matrices described below:

```
L = D^(-1/2) * A * D^(-1/2);
```

`D`, `A` and `L` are a `n*n` matrices. `A` and `L` are **not** diagonal or sparse but `D` is diagonal. In this case `n = 16900`. When I calculate `L` in matlab, it takes a long time, about 4 hours!

My question is: Is there a more efficient way to calculate `L`?

Comment: What is `D^(-1/2)`? Is the `^(-1/2)` operation taken element-wise?

Comment: No, it's not. It's regular matrix multiplication.

Comment: I think in the case of a diagonal matrix it's the same. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) twice. I'm not sure it will be faster or not:

```
v = diag(D).^(-1/2); %// this is the same as diag(D.^(-1/2))
L = bsxfun(@times, v.', bsxfun(@times, A, v));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using naive matrix multiplication, you can specialised asymptotically faster ones. Strassen's algorithm comes to mind but if I recall correctly it typically has a high constant, despite it's better asymptotic complexity. If you have a very limited set of possible values in your matrices, you can use a variation of the "four Russians" method.